# Casting don't work (int []to double[])

Tags: java, casting

I have setter method:

```
public void setValues(int[] values){
    this.values = (double[])values;        
}
```

and Java don't allow me to do that. I get message about inconvertible types. I know I can use Integers and doubleValue() method but above solution should work (I think).

So, what's wrong?

Comment: It's array of int and not int, you can create new array of double and copy each value with individual cast.

Comment: You can't randomly cast arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Casting from `int` to `double` is a different thing than casting from `int[]` to `double[]`. The later cannot work, because an array is an object. So you have 2 incompatible objects. The cast will surely fail at runtime, and hence compiler doesn't allow the cast, and gives you compiler error.

Unfortunately there is no direct way to convert from `int[]` to `double[]`. You have to write loop for that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    this.values[i] = values[i];
}
```

Or, if you can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), you can use [`Doubles.toArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray-java.util.Collection-) method:

```
this.values = Doubles.toArray(Ints.asList(values));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't mass-cast an entire array across primitives. You need to cast when retrieving the array or convert it element by element:

```
for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    this.values[i] = values[i]; //int-to-double cast implicit
}
```