# Can't cast array Object to double[]

Tags: java, casting

I read where an array of int can't be cast as double[]: [Casting Don't Work int[] to double[], 17 Oct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19438086/1639625)

I have run into a similar roadblock trying to cast an array Object of doubles to double[]. I suspect it is the same issue.

I would like to understand the limitation better. Is this a general limitation on all collections, or is it limited to arrays? Is there a fundamental reason for the limitation, or is it just something that has to be worked around?

I have a class that creates an array of doubles that represents an input signal. I pass an instance of that class to a class to calculate the FFT of the signal. The FFT class I'm using needs a double[] parameter. Since I create the input array as double[], it seems I should be able to cast it as such.

Comment: What language are you using? Please add that to the tags for this post.

Comment: Implicit conversions of arrays aren't part of the specs.  You can swing it with linq, however.  `object[] foo = new double[]{0d}; double[] done = foo.OfType<double>().ToArray();`

Comment: It is not clear to me what might be your issue. You stated that you get the `double[]` as a parameter, why do you need a cast then?

Comment: It's a general question; even a reference to documentation that explains the limitation on casting arrays would be helpful.

Comment: This is a first attempt at a project, (and at Java programming), so the code is pretty gnarled - I wouldn't want to inflict it on anyone. Here's some pseudo code:

Comment: Class A: loop to create double[] input signal, Class B: create FFT array from input signal using FastFourierTransformer(), Class C: create GUI, pass instance of A to B, getB, displayA, displayB

Comment: Thomas J.: The issue is the instance of the array is type ArrayClass, not double[]. FastFourierTransformer needs double[].

Comment: Write a loop.  Is it that hard??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting don't work (int \[\]to double\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438086/casting-dont-work-int-to-double)

Comment: What part of the Java documentation would lead you to believe that this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

> trying to cast an array Object of doubles to double[]

There is no such thing as 'an array Object of doubles' in Java. There is `double[],` there is `Double[],` and there is `Object[]` where the elements are `Doubles.`

You can cast between the last two, in both directions if the underlying type really is `Double[],` but not between the first and either of the others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained here [Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type). Covariance and contravariance does not work with value types. However, you can force the cast by using linq as Will mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: The question was tagged in Java, but seems that your answer is about C#.

Comment: It should be language independent. But thanks for pointing it out.